# Access State From Another Reducer React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, reducers

Maybe this has been answered before, but I'm having difficulty finding the answer.

I have to reducers with their own initial state. Is there a way (good practice of course) to access the initial state from one reducer?

Reducer One:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({ loadData: [] })

const reducerOne = (state = initialState, action) => { 
   switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_REPORT_FORMAT: { 
        return state.merge({ loadData: state.get('loadData') });
    }
    ....
}
```

Reducer Two:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({ newData: [] });
const reducerTwo = (state = initialState, action) => { 
   switch (action.type) {
    case GET_NEW_DATA: {
        // Is there a way to "call" the SELECT_REPORT_FORMAT in 
        // reducerOne and get its new state (state.get('loadData')) from here?
        // I did add case SELECT_REPORT_FORMAT in this reducer, and 
        // it did get called, but the state is with the property of
        // newData, which makes sense. I need to access the loadData
        // array from here.  
        return state.merge({ newData: state.get('loadData') });
    }
    ....
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the harm in exporting `initialState` and importing it where needed!

So just add `export const initialState = yourStuff` and then import it from your other reducer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need to get the end results of initial state after its being called from "SELECT_REPORT_FORMAT" in reducer one.

Comment: I mean I need the return value of state.merge({ loadData: state.get('loadData') }) inside reducer two.

Comment: Ok so not the initial state at all, you meant to say the state after some actions have been fired. In that case, no, you shouldn't be reaching into the state of other reducers since that would break encapsulation and could cause infinite loops. Why not have a component fire an action that reducerA uses in response to a change in state caused by reducerB?

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
return state.merge({ loadData: state.get('loadData') });
```

doesn't make sense really. But in any case, I would suggest to use the same value for initialState. That means that the way you have it right now is fine - for both reducers loadData and newData respectively will be empty array.

After that, when an actionCreator is called with `type: GET_DATA` and `payload: {data: 'blahBlah'}`, all you have to do, is to get this action from both of the reducers.

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({ loadData: [] })
const reducerOne = (state = initialState, action) => { 
   switch (action.type) {
    case GET_DATA: { 
        return state.merge(fromJS({ loadData: action.payload.data) }));
    }
    ....
}
```

and

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({ newData: [] });
const reducerTwo = (state = initialState, action) => { 
   switch (action.type) {
    case GET_DATA: {
        return state.merge(fromJS({ newData: action.payload.data) }));
    }
    ....
}
```

Where `action.payload.data` is the `loadData` you are trying to get in your question. Hope it helps :)